# JPEG image not showing up onto the pane - javafx

Tags: java, image, javafx, jpeg

I am currently making a small weather application and am adding images which correspond to the forecast. I have 5 different forecasts but when I use a JPEG it does not show up on the pane. I have a png and gif successfully display. Any pointers or should I just use a different image format?

```
case "Wind":   // Code to draw the graphics for Wind

                Text windText = new Text(220, 225, "Windy");
                windText.setFill(Color.RED);  // Change the pen color      
                getChildren().add(windText);
                ImageView wind = new ImageView(imgPath + "images/windJpeg.jpeg");
                wind.setFitHeight(100);
                wind.setFitWidth(100);
                wind.setX(190);
                wind.setY(100);
                getChildren().add(wind);
```

This is one of the cases which does not display an image. The only similar quality between those which don't display is that the image is a jpeg, is that the reason?

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: Does the value of `imgPath` end with a slash?  Did you print out `imgPath + "images/windJpeg.jpeg"` and verify that the path exists as either a file or resource?

Comment: @VGR Yes, imgPath ends with / and I can confirm that the path is correct and the file is there. It is the same layout that I used for .gif and .png files which display correctly.

Comment: Is it possible to share windJpeg.jpeg with us, so we can try displaying it in a JavaFX program?

Comment: could you share the full path to windjpeg.jpeg?

Comment: @VGR @Benson99 The full path is `file:/E:/IST%20242/HW6/HW6_WeatherApp_Template/HW6_WeatherApplication/` and then the photo I used can be found [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=clipart+wind&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS811US811&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=d_s6dp_ITRGeVM%253A%252CN49KO7hZF8jTJM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQFZWYGz0FpfIleeNFdKFeEEbqhMA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8-NKG2NXhAhWJY98KHcPbCPIQ9QEwBXoECAcQDg#imgrc=d_s6dp_ITRGeVM:).

Comment: and just to be thorough - is the extension jpeg or jpg? (only because I've done it myself haha)

Comment: @Benson99 You got it, I had them mixed up! I didn't even realize that, thank you. I'm not sure how to make this the correct response but it all works now.

Comment: I'd laugh at you.... but I still feel the pain of wondering where my image went and realized I had jpeg as an extension :p